# Regular Expression From a DFA

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, regular-expressions

I am trying to create a finite automate that would accept any strings that have at least to 0s but reject all strings that have consecutive 0s. I have designed a deterministic finite automaton (DFA) for this purpose but am having trouble generating a regex 
from it.

[image: DFA Diagram]

The checked boxes are accepting states.
Thank you!

Comment: See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions

Comment: You can simplify the DFA: states start and s0 are equivalent, and states s4 and s6 are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the regular expression $1^*01^+0(1^+0)^*1^*$.